# JSON iteration results... possible to sort?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, each

Is there any way to use the code below and alter it to sort $.each results alphabetically?
I was thinking there may be a way to still keep the $.each and maybe do some sort of if else  statement?  Basically, I want the val to be in order and not idx.

```
function fillsystems(mso,cb) {
    $("#station").empty().append($('<option>Loading systems...</option>'));
    mso=mso.replace("&","{08an}");
    //alert(mso);
    $.getJSON("?act=getirdsystems&mso="+mso,function(json){
        //alert(json.data);
        $("#station").empty();
        $("#station").append($('<option>Choose...</option>'));
        $.each(json.data,function(idx,val) {
        $("#station").append($('<option value='+idx+'>'+val+'</option>'));
        });
        <?php if(!$_GET['edit']) { ?>$("#station").append($('<option value="new">New System...</option>'));<?php } ?>
        if(sys!='') $("#station").val(sys);
        cb();
    },"json");
}
```

Comment: Can you add a language tag please? It looks like javascript but you can never be too sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in any useful way in your situation.

The reason for this is because your array indices have meaning (they are being put in the `value` attribute... which should have quotes around its value, by the way), and using `json.data.sort` would break that relationship. That is, assuming it is an array and not an object; if it's an object then you can't sort it anyway because it has no order.

Instead, you may wish to build an array that you *can* sort, then sort it, then create your options:

```
var selbox = document.getElementById("station"), tmp = [];
$.each(json.data,function(idx,val) {tmp.push([idx,val]);});
tmp.sort(function(a,b) {
    if( a[1] == b[1]) return 0;
    return a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 1;
});
$.each(tmp,function(_,item) {
    selbox.appendChild(new Option(item[1],item[0]));
});
```

(Side-note: Isn't [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) simple? So much useful, built-in stuff!)